# tokenReceivedCallback is not called when using MSAL AngularJS with Azure B2C

Tags: angularjs, azure-ad-b2c, bearer-token, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Doing

```
msalService.loginPopup();
```

and then:

```
$rootScope.$on("msal:loginSuccess", function () {
    console.log("loginSuccess");

    var token = msalService.userInfo.idToken;
});
```

I can see that `userInfo.isAuthenticated` is true and there's an id token present.

However, `tokenReceivedCallback` is never called.

```
msalProvider.init({
    clientID: "Client ID here",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/myb2caad.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    validateAuthority: false,
    //consentScopes: ["https://myb2caad.onmicrosoft.com/test/user_impersonation"],
    tokenReceivedCallback: function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
        debugger;
        if (token) {
            console.log('Token type: ' + tokenType + ' Token: ' + token)
        }
        else {
            console.log(errorDesc + error)
        }
    }
},
    $httpProvider // Optionally, pass http provider to inject request interceptor to attach tokens
);
```

Can you spot the problem or give some hints where to look for it?

Comment: Hi @Leniel. **tokenReceivedCallback** might only be called for sign-ins via redirections rather than prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem had to do with `hashPrefix`. The app was messing up with it.

I had to do:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

The hashPrefix was interfering with the callback.

It's mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angularjs